# Bash string replacement gives me "bad substitution"

Tags: bash, replace

I have a variable that is a url and i want to replace part of that url in bash, but i keep getting "bad substitution"

```
URL="http://hostname/project/branches/Old_Branch/package"
SRC="Old_Branch"
REP="New_Branch"

echo ${$URL/$SRC/$REP};
# desired output is http://hostname/project/branches/New_Branch/package
```

Not sure exactly where I'm going wrong...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
URL="http://hostname/project/branches/Old_Branch/package"
SRC="Old_Branch"
REP="New_Branch"

echo "${URL/$SRC/$REP}"
```

Note no `$` sigill for `URL` in `${}` =)

Comment: wow, I can't believe I was cracking my nuts for the past hour or so for this.

Comment: But why? Is there some logic in treating `URL` differently or this is just a bashism?

Comment: It's a bashism, it's named 'parameter expansion'. Maybe ksh works too